# h2 header displaying below page content

Tags: wordpress, header, themes

I have been modifying a wordpress theme and as I just began to put content in the pages, I noticed the h2 header is displaying below the content (see here:http://mefo1.ecin1prod1lnx1.com/about/history/). I can't seem to find an explanation.

Below is the page.php code. I am happy to PasteBin any other code that might be needed.

Thank you very much,

Alex

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".share").click(function(){
      jQuery(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow");
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
    });

});

</script>


        <div class="posts-column">

        <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/share.php'); ?>



                            <div class="entry">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        <?php endwhile ?>   

                             <div class="clear"></div>
                            <h2 class="page"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                        <?php else : ?>

                            <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
                            <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
                            <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/searchform.php'); ?>    

                        <?php endif; ?>                 


        </div><!--end posts-column-->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Look at your code...  You put `the_title();` after `the_content();`.  Of course it'll come after.

Comment: @kevmo314 which is exactly why the OP is asking his question.  Perhaps he doesn't understand document flow in html.  Is that a reason to deride him?  Perhaps helping him with the correct answer will benefit not just him but the community in whole.  Saying things like "of course it'll come after" doesn't help anybody but your own ego.  The OP doesn't know the answer which is why he posted.  If the answer was so obvious to him do you think he would post?

Comment: @kevmo314 and @ SRM thank you for responding! In my defense (sort of?) this is not my code, but looking at it now the answer is quite obvious. It didn't start this way, so I jumbled something up along the way. I'll blame the 100+ degree heat yesterday. Thank you both for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read what @Shaun said.  Remember, divs are block elements by default which means they will grow to take up as much room as they need.  This forces any sibling blocks to start below unless otherwise specified through css.  Move your h2 to the top of the document.  Normal document flow is left to right, top to bottom so your first div (with class "entry") will be displayed as a block level element (since you didn't specify otherwise) and it's sibling will be rendered below hence why your h2 element is not where you expect.

Comment: Thanks again SRM. I am new to a lot of CSS but it is extremely helpful to have a community of people that are willing to help.

Answer (score 3):

Move   above your div class entry